# De-obfuscate JavaScript with source-map in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, uglifyjs, source-maps

We have an **JavaScript** page in production that catches any exceptions and logs them to our database. This worked fine for a while, but now we use [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to obfuscate the code and this also obfuscates the stack trace.

I know Firefox and Chrome can de-obfuscate but it does not help us since we want to de-obfuscate exceptions that ocured in production.

We have the [source-map](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k) so what I would like to do is have our backend (php) recive the exception and de-obfuscate it with the source-map before logging it to the database.

I know the [Mozilla Source-map](https://github.com/mozilla/source-map) project can do this for node.js, but is there a way to do it in PHP ?

Comment: Maybe you could execute nodejs command in php.

Comment: Yes @huwence that is an option, but I would like to do it in PHP if posible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We figured out the koala-framework has done an implementation of (de)obfuscating of source maps in PHP.

Add koala-framework/sourcemaps as dependency via composer ( https://packagist.org/packages/koala-framework/sourcemaps )

https://github.com/koala-framework/sourcemaps

For deobfuscating you are interested in Kwf_SourceMaps_SourceMap(source_map) and getMappings() afterwards.

Comment: FYI: it is recommended to cache the results of getMappings() with igbinary/<insert serializable format> to file as it will drastically lower the time it takes to do the deobfuscating.

Comment: For future readers googling this, note that you don't query this library per line/column to resolve an error; instead, you call `getMappings` and get a gigantic array with the entire file resolved, i.e. every single line/column possible, so that you only need to get the mappings once and then run any future minified errors against the gigantic array. This is why OP suggests to cache the result of getMappings, it's an extremely slow operation since it goes through the entire file, but you only need to do it once. Also note that, even if you cache it, serialization/deserialization is also slow.

Comment: 2/2 Not as slow as using `getMappings` directly every time, but still notable. Otherwise, I can confirm it still works, just make sure to offload the process to something that is not user-facing.